How to identify the syllables of an English word?
I tried to find the formal rule or the formal algorithm on how should I identify whether the word has a closed syllable or an open syllable, but I was unsuccessful.
I thought that to understand which syllables the word consists of, one should use the transcription of the word.
For example, I had the word "garlic" and its transcription [ˈɡɑː.lɪk]. I see that there are two syllables "ɡɑː" and "lɪk". The first syllable does not end with a consonant so according to the definition I know it's an open syllable. But some links on the Internet say that I am wrong and the word garlic does not have an open syllable without a detailed explanation of why. If I use the letters of the word to form the syllables I get "gar" and "lick" and both of them end with the consonant letter so both of these syllables are closed.
So I could not find the formal and concrete answers for what I've been looking for.

What is the formal definition of a syllable in English language?
How should I identify the syllables of English word?
What is the definition of an open syllable in the word? I had the definition "It's a syllable that ends with a vowel sound and does not have a consonant sound immediately following it within the same syllable" but it seems like it has nothing to do with words such as "nine" or "cite" which as I know have the open syllables but both in their transcriptions and their writing have the closed syllable according to my definition.
What is the definition of a closed syllable? I thought that it could be defined as "A syllable that ends with a consonant sound" but perhaps I've overlooked something.

If the answer is too long, please kindly provide a reference (such as a book) where I can find the answers to such questions. I know that it's better to have one question in one thread but for me these questions are strongly interconnected.

/ˈɡɑː.lɪk/ is BrE, but AmE pronunciation of the word is /ˈɡɑːr.lɪk/ - that would explain the discrepancy you're seeing. Your definition of closed/open syllables seems right - nine and cite are one closed syllable words. Sometimes (particularly when teaching reading and writing) it makes sense to distinguish additional syllable types like VCe or vowel-r syllables, since they have their own pronunciation rules, but the base open/closed distinction is as you say.

Local people say /ˈɡɑːr.lɪk/ where I live in the UK, in fact all of the western part of England does.

@MaciejStachowski thank you. Then, I guess one of my sources is mistaken because it says that the syllable of the form "stressed vowel sound + consonant sound + silent sound e" is the open syllable. If it's wrong and my definitions are correct, then everything is much more consistent for me now.

@MaciejStachowski You should post that comment as an answer!!! The other answers here are very misleading :-/

Hello, I would like to verify whether I understood the answers to this question correctly or not. I guess I need to mention that this question is important for me because lots of rules of how I should pronounce the words in my sources are like “Take the word. If it has the letters “y” or “i” in a closed syllable (and we don’t have the silent “e” in the end of a word), then often (but not always) this letter should be pronounced as the [ɪ], as in words "sit", "gym", "trick"”. However, to apply such rules accurately, I need clarification on the questions I have raised in this thread.

So I will describe how I understood the answers and I will be so grateful if one will correct me if I am wrong.      1. To identify from which syllables a word consists of I must use a transcription of the word. If I understood it right there is no formal algorithm to identify the syllables of the word at least for now and at least for my current level of understanding English. I found information that it’s an open problem in Computer Science to develop such an algorithm so it must be a really hard problem. While I understood that there are some rules which I can try to use to do it by myself.


The definition of an open syllable as “It's a syllable that ends with a vowel sound and does not have a consonant sound immediately following it within the same syllable” is correct.



The definition of a closed syllable as “A syllable that ends with a consonant sound” is also correct.



In some sources there can be further classification of the sounds. For instance,  in my sources the syllables “vowel-r” and “stressed vowel + consonant + silent e” are the types of syllables and it's normal to classify them further.



When I have a word and its transcription, I can identify its syllables using, for example, the Cambridge Dictionary where the distinct syllables are shown by a period sign. If there is no period sign but there is a stressed vowel and there is another vowel in the word then it means that the word has two syllables. For example the word “begin” follows this pattern.



There can be different separations of the one word into syllables according to the dialect of English one uses. The words “garlic” and “garden” have different transcriptions in American and British English that’s why the type of their syllables can be classified differently.



I realized that I did not understand the syllabification of words in the Merriam-Webster Dictionary or how to use it to determine syllables. I also did not grasp its connection with the transcription of the word. I need to spend some more time thinking about it.


@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thank you, I did. Do you think my assumptions 1-6 from the comments are correct and safe to use?

@perepelart Will come back and have a look later.

OK, so regarding (1), yes. That's correct. There are a number of reasons why. First of all, take a word like "present". That could be either  /'prez.ənt/ or   /prə'zent/ depending on whether you're talking about the noun or the verb or the adjective. There are also lots of other homographs in English where words pronounced differently are spelt the same, sometime from the same word class. Thirdly, English spelling does not have a good or a regular writing sound-sound correspondence. You can't reliably deduce the stress from the written form, unless you have some kind of algorithm ...

... which can detect which word it is from the surrounding context using the frequency of co-occurrence with other words and its position in the sentence and also a database of the syllabification of every word in the English language. If you have both of those you could do detect the syllabification of a given word in a text, but that's not the kind of thing you're trying to do. You're trying to predict the syllabification from the spelling, not record the syllabification of every word from a database!

Regarding (2), correct! (where the word 'sound' is key). (5) Correct, but you don't need to worry about vowels. A stress mark is just like a syllable division. So if it's in between two different parts of a word, there are two syllables. It would just be a waste of time effort and ink to use a stress mark and a syllable mark together all the time! (6) correct. And in fact, there can be different pronunciations within the same dialect and even free variation between speakers. Take for example the word glistening:that can be either /glɪs.ən.ɪŋ/ or  /glɪs.n̩.ɪŋ/ or /glɪsnɪŋ/.

The first two pronunciations have 3 syllables, the last, 2. (7) Probably. It's always good to take a close look at the information at the beginning of a dictionary so that you understand how that dictionary's system works.  Sorry missed out (3), but that's correct! Lastly, regarding (4), that's the only incorrect one.  “vowel-r” and “stressed vowel + consonant + silent e” are not types of syllable. Those have to do with spelling. Spelling does not have any sound!!!

Oops. Sorry, in my first comment I should have written Thirdly, English spelling does not have a good or a regular writing-sound correspondence!

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thank you for your time and help! Everything makes much more sense to me now. I've realized that there is an error in paragraph 4. I should pay more attention to whether I am referring to the sounds in the syllable that I pronounce or to the spelling of the syllable using graphic symbols (letters).

@Maciej Stachowski Wrote:
/ˈɡɑː.lɪk/ is BrE, but AmE pronunciation of the word is /ˈɡɑːr.lɪk/ - that would explain the discrepancy you're seeing. Your definition of closed/open syllables seems right - nine and cite are closed syllable words. Sometimes (particularly when teaching reading and writing) it makes sense to distinguish additional syllable types like VC or vowel-r syllables, since they have their own pronunciation rules, but the base open/closed distinction is as you say.


How to identify the syllables of an English word?

The traditional source for syllable information in English is a good dictionary. I recall that 30 years ago when dictionaries were printed on paper, they all had syllabification as part of each entry. Today, not all online dictionaries have this, so you'll have to look for a good one that includes the syllables.
One example that does show syllabification is the Merriam-Webster online dictionary. Here is part of the entry for garlic:

gar·​lic (ˈgär-lik)

Notice the pronunciation is listed separately from the syllabification. This is important for words that have pronunciation guides that don't include all the letters of the word, such as for allium:

al·​li·​um (ˈa-lē-əm)

Here we see the syllabification is consistent with the guidelines outlined in other answers here. This is the easiest and fastest ways to determine the syllabification for an English word. This method is commonly used by songwriters who want to include lyrics with their music and need to put down the syllabification correctly to keep the music as readable as possible.

If I understood it correctly, in the Cambridge Dictionary the period in the transcription is used to indicate the syllables of a word. In this dictionary the word "garlic" has the transcription [ˈɡɑː.lɪk] and so we have two syllables : ˈɡɑː and lɪk -- the first is an open one and the second is closed. According to the Merriam-Webster Dictionary in American English, the syllabification (and the transcription as well) will be ˈgär-lik.

So we have we first syllable ˈgär which is closed, and the second syllable lik that is closed too. I hope I understood it correctly. Before this, I hadn't paid much attention to this period sign in the transcription but now I definitely understand why this is important. Thank you for the link to the Merriam-Webster dictionary; I will bookmark it because I know that American English is widely used and I definitely should understand both proccess of syllabification.

Sorry Todd, but you've confused the guidelines for the breaking of the orthographic word with the syllable division. Never the twain shall meet!

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Oh yeah, maybe. Probably. Is this definitely different from what the asker is looking for? I would never have thought to ask for sources on “word breaking orthography” or whatever the right term is for what my answer is about. I thought this was called “syllabification”.

@ToddWilcox "Is this definitely different from what the asker is looking for? " <-- Yes, I think so. Reason is that they give the phonetics for the word and also that's what open and closed syllables are about, really. There's no doubt though that OP is getting confused by trying to figure out spelling sound correspondences (which is hopeless for English most of the time!)

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. does the syllabification have nothing to do with the pronunciation of a word? You are right that I am trying to understand how to break a word into syllables to identify whether it has an open or a closed syllable, in order to understand how I should pronounce a word correctly.

@perepelart The syllabification has nothing to do with the spelling or writing of the word. A syllable is about how the sounds in the word are structured.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Do you think I can open a new question where I will indicate that I've understood for now so someone could say am I right or not? Or should I add it in this question? Or Do I need to write it here as comment?

@perepelart I'd write it in the comments under your question and then, if you're correct, you could edit it into your post after you get some feedback.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. thank you, I will do it once I summarise my thoughts.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. So what’s the word for what my answer is about? Oh maybe that’s an ELU question?

@ToddWilcox Word divisions seems to be the main contender. But wouldn't hurt to ask on EL&U. Make sure you ask for a source though! (Otherwise people willl just make it up!)

The formal definition of a syllable can be found in a dictionary:

a single unit of speech, either a whole word or one of the parts into which a word can be separated, usually containing a vowel

A closed syllable is a syllable that ends with a consonant sound, typically resulting in a short vowel sound, like the single syllable in 'cat'.
But most people view syllables as recognisable in pronunciation, and that can vary greatly between English dialects, such as British or US English, and between regional accents and dialects within those.
There are some general guidelines on how syllables should be recognised, such as:

Each syllable usually contains at least one vowel sound.
Consonant patterns tend to separate syllables, like consonant-vowel-consonant (CVC) patterns, which often indicate syllable boundaries (for example, "hap-py").
Recognised prefixes and suffixes usually form separate syllables, for example, "un-hap-py" or "happi-ness".
Sometimes vowel combinations form a single syllable (diphthongs), while other times each vowel sound represents a separate syllable (for example, "cre-a-tion").

And there are probably more.
If you want some examples of how syllable counts change with pronunciation:

The word 'mirror' is usually pronounced with 2 syllables 'mi-rror' by British English speakers, but many US accents pronounce just 1 and make it sound like 'murrrr' to my British ears.
The month of February is pronounced with 4 syllables ('Fe-bru-ar-y') by some, but others make it sound like just 2 ('Feb-ree')

Further, you'll find that English speakers writing poetry or songs will deliberately use alternative pronunciations that may belie their own accent if it helps fit the rhythm scheme they are working to.

That must be some hillbilly accent. https://forvo.com/search/mirror/en_uk/ AND https://forvo.com/search/mirror/en_usa/

Thank you for explaining how I should identify the syllables of the word. It's not fully clear for me  yet, but I will try to practice. I am especially thankful for pointing out that the transcription and the pronunciation of the words may depend on the dialect of English that one uses. I definitely didn't understand that before posting this question and thought that it's unified across the dialects of English. I now realize that I was mistaken and I need to take this into account.

Your post unhelpfully confuses orthographic rules for breaking words across line boundaries with syllables. Happy does not syllabify with a p in each syllable. It only has one /p/!

Many people pronounce "February" as feb-yoo-ehr-ee

As @maciejstachowski says, in American English "garlic" is pronounced GAR-lick, two closed syllables. If it's different in British English or some other dialects, that could be the source of your inconsistent information.
Note that the definition of an open syllable is that it ends with a "vowel sound", not that it ends with a vowel. So for example, "nine" ends with a vowel but it ends with a consonant sound. It is pronounced "nīn" with a long "i".
Breaking a word into syllables in English is annoyingly complicated. The GENERAL rule is, every syllable includes a vowel (or diphthong), if the vowel is followed by two consonants, the first ends the syllable and the second begins a new syllable. If it's followed by only one consonant, then the vowel ends the syllable and the consonant begins the next syllable.
So for example: "begin" is be-gin. After the "e" there is one consonant, "g", so the first syllable ends with "e" and the second begins with "g".
"happen" is "hap-pen". The two p's get split between the first and second syllables.
When two consonants combine to make a single sound, like "th" or "ch", they are treated as a single consonant for purposes of this rule. So "gather" is NOT gat-her but ga-ther.
If a word ends with an "e", it is usually part of the preceding syllable rather than making a new syllable. So "admire" is "ad-mire", the "e" is part of the second syllable.
These rules will give you the correct syllable breakout for many, probably most English words. But like so many things in English, there are special cases and exceptions.

So to define what are the syllables of the word, I need to use the transcription of the word, and both of my definitions are correct. How awesome! The word "garlic" does have an open syllable (if I use the British version of the transcription), while the words "nine" and "cite" have closed syllables. I will try to memorize and use the rules you provided to identify syllables. Thank you very much!

Vowel sounds are vowels. Your post confuses rules for breaking words across lines when writing on the one hand and syllables on the other. The term 'open syllable' doesn't refer to writing but sound/phonetics. This is going to confuse readers because, for example, there is only one /p/ in happen!!! (Unlike in lamppost, where there's two)

@nothereanymore No, "vowel sounds" and "vowels" are not the same thing. Like if I write the word "nine", it ends with an "e", a vowel, but it does not end with a vowel SOUND. It ends with an "n" sound, a consonant sound.

@nothereanymore The conventional rule for breaking words across lines is that you break at syllable boundaries. Yes, "syllables" refers to phonetics. But what's your point? I said nothing about where to break words across lines. If you're saying that the rules I cited don't apply to phonetic syllables but only to line breaks ... I think that's just incorrect.

@Jay Then how do you get two /p/s in the word "happy" for example? And what's all this stuff about if there are two consonants the first belongs with the first syllable and the second with the second? That's got nothing to do with syllables! In the word askew, the /s/ is in the second syllable, not the first, for example.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Wait, now I'm confused. You said that my distinction between a "vowel" and a "vowel sound" is bogus, but now you are distinguishing between a "consonant" and a "consonant sound". There clearly are two "p"s in "happy". One need only look at the word to see them. RE "askew", I said that when two consonants combine to make a single sound, they are not split across syllables. "sk" here is an example of that rule. It's certainly true that there are exceptions to the "split the consonants between syllables" rule, but to say that it has "nothing to do with syllables" is ...

... simply not true. I'm really not sure what you're trying to argue. That there are no rules for breaking a word into syllables? That it's a completely random and unpredictable process?

Hi Jay. Many languages all over the world have no writing system. Others, like Japanese have a writing system, but it is a syllabary and made up primarily of symbols which represent syllables, not phonemes. Chinese has a writing system, but each symbol represents a word not a phoneme. All of those languages have consonants and vowels. They also have speech streams made up of syllables. And, in fact, all spoken languages do. Now, at school when learning how to write etc, it's common to call the letters that correspond to consonants 'consonants'. We should say something like ...

... 'consonant symbols' or 'consonant letters'. Now, 'open syllable' and so forth refers to sounds as they occur in all languages, written or not. The OP clarified they were talking about sound in the comments and this was backed up by their discussion of transcriptions. And this is the reason why Maciej's comment (Which you cite) is pertinent. The spelling is the same for US and UK English, but there's a consonant sound at the end of thirst syllable in US, but not UK.

... When TEFL people or dictionaries or linguists use dashes like this: / /, they are using them to discuss phonemes/sounds not spelling. So down to business, there is no rule or even tendency for two consonants together (means real consonants, not consonant letters)  in the middle of a word to be split between a preceding or following syllable. Also, there is only one /p/ (= 'p' sound) in happy. There are two letters, but a double letter in English tells us about the preceding vowel (= sound) and tells us nothing about the consonant (= sound) it represents.

... Now dictionaries tell us where a written word can be broken up if it has to be split over two lines. This has nothing to do with the sounds in the word and the sections do not correspond to syllables (=sound) in the word. The rules that you discuss in your post all have to do with writing and not the syllables (=sound structures) that make up the words.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, it's certainly true that the sound that we say in a word and the symbol that we use to represent that sound are not the same thing. Just like a person has a name, but a person is not a name. That was, in fact, one of my original points: that a "vowel sound" and a "vowel" are not the same thing. (And whether we call the sound a "vowel" and the letter a "vowel symbol", or the sound a "vowel sound" and the letter a "vowel", or by some other terms, is not something with agreed on terminology, so the fact that I'm using different words than use doesn't change the ...

... fact that we are saying the same thing. (Despite your curious statement ridiculing me for saying this, and then later saying the same thing yourself.) That said, there is a close association between the symbols and the sounds. It is not irrational to talk about "the sound that the letter 'p' makes", etc. Yes yes, there are special cases and exceptions, more so in some languages than in others. But we can say that, IN GENERAL, "p" makes this sound.

To say that where we break a word when writing has nothing to do with syllables is simply wrong. The conventional rule is that when writing you can break a word between syllables and nowhere else. This page, http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000129.htm, for example, says that when breaking a word across lines, rule number one, break it between syllables.

Yes, dictionaries typically show syllable breaks. But it's not like they just make these up and there's no pattern or rules to it. There are generally accepted rules, basically the ones I listed in my original answer.

@Jay They show line breaks and syllable break separately. The syllable breaks are in the phonetic transcription and shown either by a full stop, a space, or by a stress mark. There aren't two /p/s in  happy.
If you split the word across lines according to its syllables, it would have to be happ and y.

I have never seen a dictionary that identifies separate line breaks and syllable breaks. American Heritage, Random House, and Collins, for example, show only one set of breaks. If you have a dictionary that has separate breaks, it's the exception, not the rule.

The word "happy" clearly has two letter "p"s. One need only look at the word to see that. If you want to say it has only one "p" SOUND, that's a different question -- and exactly the issue that you ridiculed me for when I said this could be true of vowels. Whether it's properly pronounced "HAP-py" or "HAP-y" is a very subtle difference. Personally I always pronounced it with two "p" sounds. I'm not aware of a study on how most English speakers pronounce it.

Any way, this conversation has long since ceased to be productive. Feel free to spout some more nonsense and get the last word. :-)

"I have never seen a dictionary that identifies separate line breaks and syllable breaks. American Heritage, Random House, and Collins, for example, show only one set of breaks. If you have a dictionary that has separate breaks, it's the exception, not the rule." 1/

(1) American heritage:  "dictionary" dic·tion·ar·y and (dĭk'shə-nĕr′ē) [note that the syllables don't match the line breaks].  (2)  Random House "happening"  hap pen ing and hap' ə ning (notice again they don't match) (3) Collins - don't give either. Cambridge, Oxford, Merriam-Webster they all give both the line breaks and the syllables. Merriam-W "happy" hap py and 'ha-pē.  2/

"Nonsense" indeed! ;-) 3/3
